# How to convert int to decimal in .net

Tags: c#, .net, integer, decimal

How to convert `int` to `decimal`
Example : convert 12 to 12.0

I tried below but to luck

```
int i = 10;
Decimal newValue = Decimal.parse(i)
```

and

```
Decimal newValue  = Convert.ToDecimal(i)
```

Comment: you understand that 2 different variables cannot have the same name in the same scope?

Comment: In the esteemed words of a rising dark lord, you need a teacher.

Comment: There is an explicit conversion operator - Just do `decimal d = (decimal)i;`

Comment: What makes you think that all of the answers (which are basically saying what it appears you've tried) don't work? Are you doing something like writing the value out to a string? If so, this might be ignoring the .0.

Comment: I see the value 10 back in decimal newValue instead of 10.0

Comment: int x = 100;
decimal y = x * 0.01m; //1.00
https://dotnetfiddle.net/t3j82Z

Answer (score 15):

You can't *change* local variable type:

```
  // i is integer
  int i = 10;
  // and now i become decimal 
  decimal i = decimal.parse(i); // <- doesn't compile
```

But you can *create* another local variable:

```
  int i = 10;
  decimal d = i; // d == 10M
```

And .Net *convert* `i` into `decimal` for you (and so you have integer `i == 10` and `decimal` `d == 10m`). There's an *exotic* possibility with dynamic typing

```
  dynamic i = 15;           // i is int
  i = Convert.ToDecimal(i); // now i is decimal; "(decimal) i;" will do as well
```

but I doubt if you want it. If you insist on `Parse()` you should put an ugly

```
  decimal d = decimal.Parse(i.ToString());
```

Since we parse from `String` representation only.

**Edit:**

> But still the decimal value contains only integer i.e. 10 instead of
>   10.0

Math says that

```
  10 == 10.0 == 10.00 == 10.000 == ...
```

thus if you want to change *representation*, you should use formatting:

```
  Console.Write(d.ToString("F1")); // F1 - 1 digit after the decimal point
```

in case of `decimal` (not `double`) you can play a (dirty?) trick

```
  decimal d = i + 0.0m;

  Console.Write(d); // 10.0
```

Comment: Tried all the above. But still the decimal value contains only integer i.e. 10 instead of 10.0

Answer (score 1):

decimal (or Decimal) defines an [implicit conversion operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131060(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to simply write something like this:

```
int i = 10;
decimal d = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int i = 10;
decimal d = new decimal(i);
```

Note that you cannot change the type of `i` from `int` to `decimal` on the fly; you will need to have two variables--one `int` (`i`) and one `decimal` (`d`).

Comment: sorry for the typo..I have updated that. But implicit conversion didnt work